# Make a SAS data column into a Macro variable?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

How can I convert the output of a SAS data column into a macro variable?

For example:

```
Var1 | Var2
-----------
  A  |  1
  B  |  2
  C  |  3
  D  |  4
  E  |  5
```

What if I want a macro variable containing all of the values in Var1 to use in a PROC REG or other procedure? How can I extract that column into a variable which can be used in other PROCS?

In other words, I would want to generate the equivalent statement:

```
%LET Var1 =

  A
  B
  C
  D
  E
  ;
```

But I will have different results coming from a previous procedure so I can't just do a '%LET'. I have been exploring SYMPUT and SYMGET, but they seem to apply only to **single** observations.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
proc sql;
  select var1 
    into :varlist separated by ' '
    from have;
quit;
```

creates `&varlist.` macro variable, separated by the separation character.  If you don't specify a separation character it creates a variable with the last row's value only.

There are a lot of other ways, but this is the simplest.  `CALL SYMPUTX` for example will do the same thing, except it's complicated to get it to pull all rows into one.

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt and helpful reply. That did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in a proc directly, no need for a macro variable. I used numeric values for your var1 for simplicity, but you get the idea.

```
data test;
input var1  var2 @@;
datalines;
1 100 2 200 3 300 4 400 5 500
run;



proc reg data=TEST;
MODEL VAR1 = VAR2;
RUN;
```